# $location is not defined in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In the below , roles.js file whenever the onSelect function is called if the role is UserRole i'm navigating user to different page

```
angular.module('myApp.roles', ['ngRoute'])
       .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
           $routeProvider.when('/roles', {
           templateUrl: 'roles/roles.html',
           controller: 'PostsCtrl',
           selector: 'roles'
       });
       $routeProvider.when('/footer', {
           templateUrl: 'footer/footer.html',
           controller: 'footerCtrl'
       });
      }])

      .controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', function ($scope,
        $rootScope, $log, $location) {
           $scope.onSelect = function (A, B, C) {
               localStorage.setItem("A", JSON.stringify(A));
               localStorage.setItem("B", JSON.stringify(B));
               localStorage.setItem("C", JSON.stringify(C));
               if (role.roleName === "User Role") {
                   $rootScope.roles = [];
                   $location.url("/footer");
               } else {
                   $rootScope.mangoes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("B"));
        }
    };
}]);
```

I have defined `$location` in the controller and added it as parameter in function . When i debugged it then i found that `$location` is  `undefined`. Error is :Cannot read property 'url' of undefined.

Comment: fix your injections: `['$scope', '$rootScope', '$log','$location' ,function($scope, $rootScope, $log, $location) {`, you were missing `$log`

Comment: Thank you All...Missed checking the Injecting parameters....

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the order while injecting parameters, remove **`$log`** from the parameters,

```
.controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location' ,function ($scope,
 $rootScope, $location) {
```